# Create a range of day names from day nums?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of day nums that I'd like to convert to a prettier string format. The corresponding day names have to be displayed as a range.

Here is an example:

```
// 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday

days = [0,1,2,4,5];
// Should be ["Sunday-Tuesday", "Thursday-Friday"]

days = [0,1,3,5,6]
// Should be ["Friday-Monday", "Wednesday"]
// note that this wraps around!!
```

I have tried and *somewhat succeeded*, but it does not wrap around. Also it is **ugly**, imo.

```
let result = [];
let build = "";
let previous = -10;
let days = [0,1,3,5,6];

for(let i=0;i < days.length; i++) {
    let d = parseInt(days[i]);

    if (d !== previous+1 && i > 0) {
        build = build.slice(1).split(",");
        if (build.length == 1) 
            build = build[0];
        else if (build.length > 0) {
           build = build[0] + "-" + build[build.length-1];
        }
        result.push(build);
        build = "";
    }

    build = build + "," + getDayName(d);

    if (i === days.length-1) {
        build = build.slice(1).split(",");
        if (build.length == 1) 
            build = build[0];
        else if (build.length > 0) {
           build = build[0] + "-" + build[build.length-1];
        }
        result.push(build);
    }
    previous = d;
}
```

This will only print out `Array [ "Sunday-Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday-Saturday" ]`.

How can I make the days wrap around? And is there a much cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: You probably want an array of day names. The day number modulo 7 will give you the index into the array. Then if you previously stopped at Friday, for example, add that day number (5) to the day numbers of your current list.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the days wrap around"? Are you talking about, for instance, [5, 6, 0, 1, 2], and that should give "Friday-Tuesday"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the first consecutive dates onto the end of the array so that when we run the algorithm to group them, the wrap is automatically handled.

```
let names = 'Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday'.split(',');
let i = 0;
while (days[i]+1 == days[i+1]) i++;
days = days.concat(days.splice(0, i+1));
let res = [];
let s = days[0];
for (i = 0; i < days.length-1; i++){
    if ((days[i]+1)%7 != days[i+1]){
        let f = days[i];
        res.push(s == f ? names[s] : names[s]+'-'+names[f]);
        s = days[i+1];
    }
}
f = days[days.length-1];
res.push(s == f ? names[s] : names[s]+'-'+names[f]);
res.unshift(res.pop());
```

Comment: `[0, 2, 4]` was changed to `[2, 4, 0]`. But beautiful.

Comment: According to the Question post, when input is `[0,1,2,4,5]`, expected output is `["Sunday-Tuesday", "Thursday-Friday"]`. But your code outputs `["Thursday-Friday", "Sunday-Tuesday"]`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't make it clear in the description about ordering. But out of curiosity (point raised by @set0gut1), how would you reorder `res` such that `Monday` is first? If there is no Monday, then the next one is the next available day? So `["Friday-Tues", "Thursday"]` and `["Thurs", "Fri-Sun"]` is also fine.

Comment: When input is `[0,2,4]`, current code outputs `['Thursday', 'Sunday', 'Tuesday']`. Is this ok?

Comment: I tested it, and it works given the original description above, but the extra tidbit about ordering still doesn't work. I ran the same input that @set0gut1 gave `[0,2,4]` and it does output in incorrect order. It should be `['Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday']`. I guess since this solves the original question, I'll mark it as answered. But it would be cool if the ordering was also addressed.

Comment: @tempomax It is not simple to order it with Sunday at the end as you have defined Sunday to be `0` and Monday to be `1` (i.e. Sunday *before* Monday). I would suggest you just change the name definitions to the order you want. In other words, it is not clear on which day your week starts... from the question, your week appears to start on a Sunday, not a Monday.

Comment: Ah okay. What would it be if Sunday is the first day then, so it would be `["Sunday", "Tuesday", "Thursday"]`?

Comment: @tempomax Yes, that is the current output.

Answer (score 0):

If divide the problem into next three steps, it will become simple.

1. chunking into consecutive elements, such that `[[0, 1], [3], [5, 6]]`
2. deal with wrap around, such that `[[5, 6, 0, 1], [3]]`
3. convert to string, such that `['Friday-Monday', 'Wednesday']`

```js
const convert = dayNumbers => {
  // 1. chunking into consecutive elements, such that [[0, 1], [3], [5, 6]]
  let chunks = []
  dayNumbers.forEach(num => {
    if (chunks.length === 0) chunks.unshift([num])
    else if (chunks[0][0] === num - 1) chunks[0].unshift(num)
    else chunks.unshift([num])
  })
  chunks = chunks.map(c => c.reverse()).reverse()

  // 2. deal with wrap around, such that [[5, 6, 0, 1], [3]]
  let chunksLength = chunks.length
  if (chunksLength >= 2) {
    let lastChunk = chunks[chunksLength - 1]
    if (chunks[0][0] === 0 && lastChunk[lastChunk.length - 1] === 6) {
      chunks[0] = lastChunk.concat(chunks[0])
      chunks = chunks.splice(0, chunksLength - 1)
    }
  }

  // 3. convert to string, such that ['Friday-Monday', 'Wednesday']
  const dayNames = [
    'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
    'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
  ]
  const result = chunks.map(c => {
    if (c.length === 1) return dayNames[c[0]]
    else return dayNames[c[0]] + '-' + dayNames[c[c.length - 1]]
  })

  return result
}

console.log(convert([0, 1, 2, 4, 5])) // ['Sunday-Tuesday', 'Thursday-Friday']
console.log(convert([0, 1, 3, 5, 6])) // ['Friday-Monday', 'Wednesday']
```

Answer (score 0):

I break the problem down into two steps:

- Find consecutive ranges in a sequence of numbers
- Convert known consecutive ranges into pretty day ranges

The code I've attached here does this. `groupRanges` looks at any range, works through it grouping items into consecutive ranges. This means it'll take `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]` and convert it into `[[0, 1, 2], [4, 5]]`.

Note that if you gave it `[5, 0, 1, 2, 4]` it would ignore the fact that `4` and `5` *would* be consecutive. If you wish to treat that as consecutive you should sort any such array before passing it in.

`prettyRange` just deals with the three cases of:

- Range is empty (return empty string)
- Range has one item (return human-readable version of single item)
- Range has more than one item (assume range is a consecutive range and make human-readable version by doing -

The `groupRanges` function uses [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as (what I think is) a clean solution.

```js
const days1 = [0,1,2,4,5];
const days2 = [0,1,3,5,6];
const days3 = [0,2];
const days4 = [5,1,4];
const days5 = [4];
const daysVariants = [days1, days2, days3, days4, days5];

/**
 * @param {number[]} numbers - An array of numbers from 0-6
 * @return {number[][]} An array of an array of numbers. Each array of numbers will be consecutive in ascending order
 */
function groupRanges(numbers) {
  // Loop over numbers, building an array as we go starting with [].
  return numbers.reduce((ranges, next) => {
    // It's our first number so just return a single-item range
    if (ranges.length <= 0) return [[next]];
    const lastRange = last(ranges);
    const lastNumber = last(lastRange);
    // Next number is consecutive to the last number in the last-seen range, so we should add it to that range
    if (next - lastNumber === 1) return [...ranges.slice(0, -1), [...lastRange, next]]
    // Next number is _not_ consecutive so we add a new single-item range
    return [...ranges, [next]];
  }, []);
}

function last(array) {
  return array[array.length - 1];
}

daysVariants
  .map(groupRanges)
  .forEach(i => console.log(i));
  
const DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
function prettyRange(range) {
  if (range.length === 0) return '';
  if (range.length === 1) return DAYS[range[0]];
  return DAYS[range[0]] + '-' + DAYS[last(range)];
}

daysVariants
  .map(groupRanges)
  .forEach(ranges => ranges.map(prettyRange).forEach(i => console.log(i)));
```